# Configuring Sound Card in BeagleBone Black

Tags: codec, beagleboneblack, device-tree, soundcard

I am trying to integrate the ADAU1761 codec with the Beaglebone Black. I need to configure a sound card in order to play audio through the codec. 
I tried writing device tree overlay but did not succeed. Then I tried changing directly in the device tree.
Now the modes of the PINS are changed but the sound card is not getting configured.
am I going in the right direction? Please help.
Below are the changes I made in the device tree:

Pins mode change i2c:

```
pinmux_i2c2_pins {                                  
pinctrl-single,pins = <0x178 0x0b 0x17c 0x0b>;
                    linux,phandle = <0x30>;
                    phandle = <0x30>;
```

Pins mode change i2s:

```
 mcasp0_pins {
    pinctrl-single,pins = <0x1ac 0x08 0x19c 0x2 0x194 0x08 0x190 0x08
0x6c 0x7 0x198 0x08>;
linux,phandle = <0x47>;
phandle = <0x47>;
};
```

Driver loading:

```
i2c@4819c000 {
        compatible = "ti,omap4-i2c";
        #address-cells = <0x1>;
        #size-cells = <0x0>;
        ti,hwmods = "i2c3";
        reg = <0x4819c000 0x1000>;
        interrupts = <0x1e>;
        status = "okay";
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <0x30>;
        clock-frequency = <0x186a0>;
        linux,phandle = <0x9d>;
        phandle = <0x9d>;

                    adau1761: adau1361@38 {
                            compatible = "adi,adau1761";
                            reg = <0x38>;
                    };
```

Sound Card:

```
sound {
                compatible = "adi,adau1761-evm-audio";
                ti,model = "ADI ADAU1761";
                ti,audio-codec = <&adau1761>;
                ti,mcasp-controller = <0x52>;
                ti,audio-routing =
                "Headphone Jack",       "LOUT",
                "Headphone Jack",       "ROUT",
                "LINE1L",               "LAUX",
                "LINE1R",               "RAUX";
                clocks = <0x53>;
                clock-names = "mclk";
        };
```